# Cognos condiotional style highlight top values

Tags: styles, conditional-statements, crosstab, cognos

I have a cross tab where I'm trying to apply a conditional style to a set of rows where the row data item 'Measure' starts with the word 'Channel'. I have a rank formula to get the values ordered so I can get the top three. I want to change the background for those top three values.

I have the following data item 'Percentage Style' from a data set:

case when
[C].[C_Segment_Journey_Metrics_Data_Set_Data_Module].[Query1_0].[Percentage_] is not null and [C].[C_Segment_Journey_Metrics_Data_Set_Data_Module].[Query1_0].[Measure_Name] starts with 'Channel'
then rank(case when [C].[C_Segment_Journey_Metrics_Data_Set_Data_Module].[Query1_0].[Measure_Name] starts with 'Channel'
then [C].[C_Segment_Journey_Metrics_Data_Set_Data_Module].[Query1_0].[Percentage_]
else null
end desc
for case when [C].[C_Segment_Journey_Metrics_Data_Set_Data_Module].[Query1_0].[Measure_Name] starts with 'Channel'
then [C].[C_Segment_Journey_Metrics_Data_Set_Data_Module].[Query1_0].[Segment_Desc]
else null
end)
else null
end

and the conditional style applied to the percentage field from the same data set:

[Query1].[Percentage Style] between 1 and 3
and [Query1].[Measure_Name] starts with 'Channel'

This works if I have the 'Percentage Style' data item on the report as a column beside 'Percentage'. Both are under the 'Segment Desc' data item as columns.

I've tried adding 'Percentage Style' as an item in the property list of 'Segment Desc' but that gives very different results. The 'Percentage Style' doesn't seem to calculate in the same way. I'm not sure what else to try at this point. I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe able this using Report Expressions rather than actual data items.  If your data is already sorted from highest to lowest you won't need the Rank and you could get away with the RowNumber() expression.

Here is an example:

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/15.4/"           expressionLocale="en-us" useStyleVersion="11.5">

            <drillBehavior/>
            <layouts>
                <layout>
                    <reportPages>
                        <page name="Page1">
                            <style>
                                <defaultStyles>
                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                                </defaultStyles>
                            </style>
                            <pageBody>
                                <style>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                </style>
                                <contents><crosstab horizontalPagination="true" name="Crosstab1" refQuery="Query1">
        <crosstabCorner>
            <contents/>
            <style>
                <defaultStyles>
                    <defaultStyle refStyle="xm"/>
                </defaultStyles>
            </style>
        </crosstabCorner>


        <noDataHandler>
            <contents>
                <block>
                    <contents>
                        <textItem>
                            <dataSource>
                                <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                            </dataSource>
                        </textItem>
                    </contents>
                    <style>
                        <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                    </style>
                </block>
            </contents>
        </noDataHandler>
        <style>
            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
            <defaultStyles>
                <defaultStyle refStyle="xt"/>
            </defaultStyles>
        </style>
    <crosstabRows><crosstabNode><crosstabNestedNodes><crosstabNode><crosstabNodeMembers><crosstabNodeMember refDataItem="Order method type" edgeLocation="e2"><style><defaultStyles><defaultStyle refStyle="ml"/></defaultStyles></style><contents><textItem><dataSource><memberCaption/></dataSource></textItem><textItem><dataSource><reportExpression>RowNumber ()</reportExpression></dataSource></textItem></contents><sortList><sortItem sortOrder="descending" refDataItem="Revenue"/></sortList></crosstabNodeMember></crosstabNodeMembers></crosstabNode></crosstabNestedNodes><crosstabNodeMembers><crosstabNodeMember refDataItem="Product line code" edgeLocation="e1"><style><defaultStyles><defaultStyle refStyle="ml"/></defaultStyles></style><contents><textItem><dataSource><memberCaption/></dataSource></textItem></contents></crosstabNodeMember></crosstabNodeMembers></crosstabNode></crosstabRows><crosstabFactCell><contents><textItem><dataSource><cellValue/></dataSource></textItem></contents><style><defaultStyles><defaultStyle refStyle="mv"/></defaultStyles></style></crosstabFactCell><crosstabColumns><crosstabNode><crosstabNodeMembers><crosstabNodeMember refDataItem="Revenue" edgeLocation="e3"><style><defaultStyles><defaultStyle refStyle="ml"/></defaultStyles></style><contents><textItem><dataSource><memberCaption/></dataSource></textItem></contents></crosstabNodeMember></crosstabNodeMembers></crosstabNode></crosstabColumns><crosstabIntersections><crosstabIntersection row="e2" column="e3"><conditionalStyleRefs><conditionalStyleRef refConditionalStyle="Conditional Style 1"/></conditionalStyleRefs></crosstabIntersection></crosstabIntersections></crosstab></contents>
                            </pageBody>
                        </page>
                    </reportPages>
                </layout>
            </layouts>
        <queries><query name="Query1"><source><model/></source><selection><dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Product line code"><expression>[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line code]</expression><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="1"/></XMLAttributes></dataItem><dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Order method type"><expression>[Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method type]</expression><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/></XMLAttributes></dataItem><dataItem aggregate="total" name="Revenue"><expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Revenue]</expression><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/></XMLAttributes></dataItem></selection></query></queries><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="decimalSeparator" value="."/></XMLAttributes><modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples_LG_DQ&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO Sales (query)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath><namedConditionalStyles><advancedConditionalStyle name="Conditional Style 1"><styleCases><styleCase><style><CSS value="background-color:yellow"/></style><reportCondition>[Query1].[Product line code]= 991 and RowNumber ()&lt;=3</reportCondition></styleCase></styleCases><styleDefault/></advancedConditionalStyle></namedConditionalStyles></report>
```